# Popup should close when i clicked anywhere Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really new on Jquery and I have this code that I'm playing with. I can't find where is the script in this code that lets you close the popup anywhere. If none what and where should I put the code.

```
(function($) {

  var ie6 = (jQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version, 10) < 7 && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version, 10) > 4);

  if ($.proxy === undefined)
  {
    $.extend({
      proxy: function( fn, thisObject ) {
        if ( fn )
        {
          proxy = function() { return fn.apply( thisObject || this, arguments ); };
        };
        return proxy;
      }
    });
  };

  $.extend( jQuery.easing,
  {
    easeOutBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
      if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
      return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*((s+1)*t + s) + 1) + b;
    }
  });

  $.extend($.expr[':'], {
    value: function(a) {
      return $(a).val();
    }
  });

  $.extend({
    MsgBoxObject: {
      defaults    : {
                      name            : 'jquery-msgbox',
                      zIndex          : 10000,
                      width           : 400,
                      height          : 310,
                      background      : '#FFFFFF',
                      modal           : true,
                      overlay         : {
                                        'background-color'  : '#000000',
                                    'opacity'           : 0.5
                                    },
                  showDuration    : 200,
                  closeDuration   : 100,
                  moveDuration    : 500,
                  shake           : {
                                    'distance'   : 10,
                                    'duration'   : 100,
                                    'transition' : 'easeOutBack',
                                    'loops'      : 2
                                  },
                  emergefrom      : 'top'
                },
  options     : {},
  esqueleto   : {
                  msgbox  : [],
                  wrapper : [],
                  form    : [],
                  buttons : []
                },
  visible     : false,
  i           : 0,
  animation   : false,

  overlay : {
    create: function(options) {
      this.options = options;
      this.element = $('<div id="'+new Date().getTime()+'"></div>');
      this.element.css($.extend({}, {
        'position'  : 'fixed',
        'top'       : 0,
        'left'      : 0,
        'opacity'   : 0,
        'display'   : 'none',
        'z-index'   : this.options.zIndex
      }, this.options.style));

      this.element.click( $.proxy(function(event) {
        if (this.options.hideOnClick)
        {
          if ($.isFunction(this.options.callback))
          {
            this.options.callback();
          }
          else
          {
            this.hide();
          }
        }
        event.preventDefault();
      }, this));

      this.hidden = true;
      this.inject();
      return this;
    },

    inject: function() {
      this.target = $(document.body);
      this.target.append(this.element);

      if(ie6)
      {
        this.element.css({'position': 'absolute'});
        var zIndex = parseInt(this.element.css('zIndex'));
        if (!zIndex)
        {
          zIndex = 1;
          var pos = this.element.css('position');
          if (pos == 'static' || !pos)
          {
            this.element.css({'position': 'relative'});
          }
          this.element.css({'zIndex': zIndex});
        }
        zIndex = (!!(this.options.zIndex || this.options.zIndex === 0) && zIndex > this.options.zIndex) ? this.options.zIndex : zIndex - 1;
        if (zIndex < 0)
        {
          zIndex = 1;
        }
        this.shim = $('<iframe id="IF_'+new Date().getTime()+'" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 src=""></div>');
        this.shim.css({
          zIndex    : zIndex,
          position  : 'absolute',
          top       : 0,
          left      : 0,
          border    : 'none',
          width     : 0,
          height    : 0,
          opacity   : 0
        });
        this.shim.insertAfter(this.element);
        $('html, body').css({
          'height'      : '100%',
          'width'       : '100%',
          'margin-left' : 0,
          'margin-right': 0
        });
      }
    },

    resize: function(x, y) {
      this.element.css({ 'height': 0, 'width': 0 });
      if (this.shim) this.shim.css({ 'height': 0, 'width': 0 });

      var win = { x: $(document).width(), y: $(document).height() };

      this.element.css({
        'width'   : '100%',
        'height'  : y ? y : win.y
      });

      if (this.shim)
      {
        this.shim.css({ 'height': 0, 'width': 0 });
        this.shim.css({
          'position': 'absolute',
          'left'    : 0,
          'top'     : 0,
          'width'   : this.element.width(),
          'height'  : y ? y : win.y
        });
      }
      return this;
    },

    show: function() {
      if (!this.hidden) return this;
      if (this.transition) this.transition.stop();
      this.target.bind('resize', $.proxy(this.resize, this));
      this.resize();
      if (this.shim) this.shim.css({'display': 'block'});
      this.hidden = false;

      this.transition = this.element.fadeIn(this.options.showDuration, $.proxy(function(){
        this.element.trigger('show');
      }, this));

      return this;
    },

    hide: function() {
      if (this.hidden) return this;
      if (this.transition) this.transition.stop();
      this.target.unbind('resize');
      if (this.shim) this.shim.css({'display': 'none'});
      this.hidden = true;

      this.transition = this.element.fadeOut(this.options.closeDuration, $.proxy(function(){
        this.element.trigger('hide');
        this.element.css({ 'height': 0, 'width': 0 });
      }, this));

      return this;
    }
  },

  create: function() {
    this.options = $.extend(true, this.defaults, this.options);

    this.overlay.create({
      style         : this.options.overlay,
      hideOnClick   : !this.options.modal,
      zIndex        : this.options.zIndex-1,
      showDuration  : this.options.showDuration,
      closeDuration : this.options.closeDuration
    });

    this.esqueleto.msgbox = $('<div class="'+this.options.name+'"></div>');
    this.esqueleto.msgbox.css({
      'display'   : 'none',
      'position'  : 'absolute',
      'top'       : 0,
      'left'      : 0,
      'width'     : this.options.width,
      'height'    : this.options.height,
      'z-index'   : this.options.zIndex,
      'word-wrap' : 'break-word',
      '-moz-box-shadow'         : '0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
      '-webkit-box-shadow'      : '0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
      'box-shadow'              : '0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
      '-moz-border-radius'      : '6px',
      '-webkit-border-radius'   : '6px',
      'border-radius'           : '6px',
      'background-color'        : this.options.background
    });

    this.esqueleto.wrapper = $('<div class="'+this.options.name+'-wrapper"></div>');
    this.esqueleto.msgbox.append(this.esqueleto.wrapper);

    this.esqueleto.form = $('<form action="'+this.options.formaction+'" method="post"></form>');
    this.esqueleto.wrapper.append(this.esqueleto.form);

    this.esqueleto.wrapper.css({
      height       : (ie6 ? 80 : 'auto'),
      'min-height' : 80,
      'zoom'       : 1
    });

    $('body').append(this.esqueleto.msgbox);

    this.addevents();
    return this.esqueleto.msgbox;
  },

  addevents: function() {
    $(window).bind('resize', $.proxy(function() {
      if (this.visible)
      {
        this.overlay.resize();
        this.moveBox();
      }
    }, this));

    $(window).bind('scroll', $.proxy(function() {
      if (this.visible)
      {
        this.moveBox();
      }
    }, this));

    this.esqueleto.msgbox.bind('keydown', $.proxy(function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 27)
      {
        this.close(false);
      }
    }, this));

    // heredamos los eventos, desde el overlay (Events inherited from the overlay):
    this.overlay.element.bind('show', $.proxy(function() { $(this).triggerHandler('show'); }, this));
    this.overlay.element.bind('hide', $.proxy(function() { $(this).triggerHandler('close'); }, this));

  },

  show: function(txt, options, callback) {
    var types = ['alert', 'info', 'error', 'prompt', 'confirm'];

    this.esqueleto.msgbox.queue(this.options.name, $.proxy(function( next ) {

      options = $.extend(true, {
        type  : 'alert',
        form  : {
                  'active' : false
                }
      }, options || {});

      if (typeof options.buttons === "undefined")
      {
        if (options.type == 'confirm' || options.type == 'prompt')
        {
          var buttons = [
            {type: 'cancel', value: 'Cancel'}
          ];
        }
      }
      else
      {
        var buttons = options.buttons;
      };

      this.callback = $.isFunction(callback) ? callback : function(e) {};

      this.esqueleto.buttons = $('<div class="'+this.options.name+'-buttons"></div>');
      this.esqueleto.form.append(this.esqueleto.buttons);

      if (options.type != 'prompt')
      {
        $.each(buttons, $.proxy(function(i, button) {
          if (button.type == 'cancel')
          {
            this.esqueleto.buttons.append($('<button type="button">'+button.value+'</button>').bind('click', $.proxy(function(e) { this.close(false); e.preventDefault(); }, this)));
          }
        }, this));
      }

      this.esqueleto.form.prepend(txt);

      $.each(types, $.proxy(function(i, e) {
        this.esqueleto.wrapper.removeClass(this.options.name+'-'+e);
      }, this));
      this.esqueleto.wrapper.addClass(this.options.name+'-'+options.type);

      this.moveBox(); // set initial position

      this.visible = true;
      this.overlay.show();

      this.esqueleto.msgbox.css({
        display : 'block',
        left    : ( ($(document).width() - this.options.width) / 2)
      });

      this.moveBox();

      setTimeout($.proxy(function() { var b = $('input, button', this.esqueleto.msgbox); if (b.length) { b.get(0).focus();} }, this), this.options.moveDuration);
    }, this));


    this.i++;

    if (this.i==1)
    {
      this.esqueleto.msgbox.dequeue(this.options.name);
    }

  },

  moveBox: function() {
    var size   = { x: $(window).width(),      y: $(window).height() };
    var scroll = { x: $(window).scrollLeft(), y: $(window).scrollTop() };
    var height = this.esqueleto.msgbox.outerHeight();
    var y      = 0;
    var x      = 0;

    // vertically center
    y = scroll.x + ((size.x - this.options.width) / 2);

    if (this.options.emergefrom == "bottom")
    {
      x = (scroll.y + size.y + 80);
    }
    else // top
    {
      x = (scroll.y - height) - 80;
    }

    if (this.visible)
    {

      if (this.animation)
      {
        this.animation.stop;
      }

      this.animation = this.esqueleto.msgbox.animate({
        left  : y,
        top   : scroll.y + ((size.y - height) / 2)
      }, {
        duration  : this.options.moveDuration,
        queue     : false,
        easing    : 'easeOutBack'
      });

    }
  },

  close: function(param) {
    this.esqueleto.msgbox.css({
      display : 'none',
      top     : 0
    });

    this.visible = false;

    if ($.isFunction(this.callback))
    {
      this.callback.apply(this, $.makeArray(param));
    }

    setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
      this.i--;
      this.esqueleto.msgbox.dequeue(this.options.name);
    }, this), this.options.closeDuration);

    if (this.i==1) 
    {
      this.overlay.hide();
    }

    this.moveBox();

    this.esqueleto.form.empty();
  },
},

msgbox: function(txt, options, callback) {
  if (typeof txt == "object")
  {
    $.MsgBoxObject.config(txt);
  }
  else
  {
    return $.MsgBoxObject.show(txt, options, callback);
      }
    }

  });

  $(function() {
    if (parseFloat($.fn.jquery) > 1.2) {
      $.MsgBoxObject.create();
    } else {
      throw "The jQuery version that was loaded is too old. MsgBox requires jQuery 1.3+";
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Every tips and help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Wayyy too much code here. Try to only include what's relevant

Comment: Did you consider checking the docs? https://github.com/composite/jQuery.MsgBox/wiki#manual-close-msgbox

Answer (score 0):

this is the method this plugin is using to hide.

```
hide: function() {
  if (this.hidden) return this;
  if (this.transition) this.transition.stop();
  this.target.unbind('resize');
  if (this.shim) this.shim.css({'display': 'none'});
  this.hidden = true;

  this.transition = this.element.fadeOut(this.options.closeDuration, $.proxy(function(){
    this.element.trigger('hide');
    this.element.css({ 'height': 0, 'width': 0 });
  }, this));

  return this;
}
```

And this is the place where using this function:

```
this.element.click( $.proxy(function(event) {
    if (this.options.hideOnClick)
    {
      if ($.isFunction(this.options.callback))
      {
        this.options.callback();
      }
      else
      {
        this.hide();
      }
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }, this));

  this.hidden = true;
  this.inject();
  return this;
},
```

So according to this when you click on the overlay popup will hide using `this.hide()` method.